# Python - input from user

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def _main_(userInput1):
   if userInput1 ==create:
      userName1=input('Please enter your username : ')
      password1=input('Please enter your password : ')                       
      createAccount(userName1, password1)
   else:
      userName2=input('Please enter your username : ')
      password2=input('Please enter your password : ')
      logIn(userName2,password2)
userInput1=input('Would you like to create a account or long in, type create or login ')

_main_(userInput1)
```

I keep getting an error with:

> 'create' is not defined

Can someone help please?

Comment: `create` is likely not in scope.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `userInput1 == 'create'`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking whether `userInput1` is equal to the string `create`, you need to put `create` in quotes, like this: `'create'`, or this `"create"`. Otherwise, Python checks if `userInput1` is equal to the *variable* `create`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `if userInput1 == create` to `if userInput1 == "create"` as when you asked the user if they wanted to create a user, the input is by default a string and so you need quotes to tell the compiler to recognize it as a string rather than it seeing `create` as a *variable*.

Comment: I'm being a bit technical, buts it's probably the _parser_ not the _compiler_ which tries to recognize the string.